# Magento API V2 catalogProductAttributeAddOption (with compliance mode) - add attribute

Tags: api

I am trying to call catalogProductAttributeAddOption with V2 of Magento's API with compliance mode enabled but am getting:

```
call to undefined method stdClass::catalogProductAttributeAddOption()
```

My immediate observation was that this method is not present as soon as compliance mode is switched on. Therefore, I added (what I think are) the correct nodes to a wsi.xml file within a custom module:

```
<xsd:element name="catalogProductAttributeAddOptionRequestParam">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="attribute" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="data" type="typens:catalogProductAttributeOptionEntityToAdd"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

etc..

This ensures that the method is displayed within the WSDL and matches the same pattern as other existing methods.

Now I am just trying to figure out where this method actually needs to be defined. Am I right in thinking there should be a Api2.php file within Catalog/Model where this should happen?

Is this method already defined somewhere to work without compliance mode which could be modified? I have searched globally and can't find a thing

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to modify any source file as implementation for WS-I and non WS-I modes is the same. However service description is different.
You need to merge the following content into `Mage/Catalog/etc/wsi.xml` that will enable `catalogProductAttributeAddOption()` method in WS-I mode:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
             targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
            <xsd:element name="catalogProductAttributeAddOptionRequestParam">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="attribute" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="data" type="typens:catalogProductAttributeOptionEntityToAdd" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="catalogProductAttributeAddOptionResponseParam">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="xsd:boolean" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeAddOptionRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeAddOptionRequestParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeAddOptionResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeAddOptionResponseParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="catalogProductAttributeAddOption">
            <wsdl:documentation>Add option to attribute</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="typens:catalogProductAttributeAddOptionRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="typens:catalogProductAttributeAddOptionResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="catalogProductAttributeAddOption">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inchoo have a pretty good article on extending the V2 API which may help: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/